# Can you delete all the lines of a .txt file after a specific line?

Tags: python

I am trying to delete all the lines in a text file after a line that contains a specific string. What I am trying to do is find the number of the line in said file and rewrite the whole text up until that line.

The code that I'm trying is the following:

```
import itertools as it
with open('sampletext.txt', "r") as rf:
    for num, line in enumerate(rf, 1): #Finds the number of the line in which a specific string is contained
        if 'string' in line:
            print(num)
    with open('sampletext_copy.txt', "w") as wf:
        for line in it.islice(rf, 0, num):
            wf.write(line)
```

Also would appreciate any tips on how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Is the goal to remove the data from the original file, or just make a copy with the extra data? Your code as written would do the latter (inefficiently) if you just added `rf.seek(0)` before the second loop and added a `break` inside the `if` test after `print`ing so it wouldn't keep reading lines. There are somewhat more efficient solutions with equivalent behavior, and *much* more efficient solutions if you plan to rewrite the file in place.

Comment: You can simply open the file with read and write privileges, then read line by line and, when you found it, truncate the file with `file.truncate()`, which will make sure there's nothing afterwards. That would change the file in-place. If you want to create another file like this, you can make the same but with a copy from the original

Comment: Please describe what's wrong with your code. [ask], [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
with open('sampletext.txt', "r") as rf, open('sampletext_copy.txt', "w") as wf:
    for line in rf:
        if 'string' in line:
            break
        wf.write(line)
```

Basically, you open both files at the same time, then read the input file line-by-line. If `string` is in the line, then you're done - otherwise, write it to the output file.

Comment: No need for the `else` when the `if` unconditionally `break`s. Both files can also be opened in the same `with` to reduce the amount of indentation for the code in the body.

Comment: Also, one can use multiple `open` calls in the same line, along the start of the `with` block, to shorten it and, arguably, make it more readable

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks y'all!

Comment: Just realized, the OP wants to delete all lines *after* a specific line. This deletes those lines, plus the specific line itself. You'd want to move `wf.write(line)` before the `if`/`break` to preserve that line (obviously, if the OP wasn't speaking precisely, this might already be the correct answer, and would be correct for some others solving similar problems).

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement [Donut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69946111/364696), if you want to modify the file in-place, there's a *much* more efficient solution:

```
with open('sampletext.txt', "r+") as f:
    for line in iter(f.readline, ''):  # Can't use for line in f: because it disables
                                       # tell for txt
    # Or for walrus lovers:
    # while line := f.readline():
        if 'string' in line:
            f.seek(0, 1)  # Needed to ensure underlying handle matches logical read
                          # position; f.seek(f.tell()) is logically equivalent
            f.truncate()
            break
```

If [issue #70346](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/70346) is ever fixed (so calling `truncate` on a file actually `truncate`s at the logical position, not the arbitrary position of the underlying raw handle that's likely advanced a great deal due to buffering), this simpler code would work:

```
with open('sampletext.txt', "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'string' in line:
            f.truncate()
            break
```

If you want to delete the tested-for line as well, not just the following lines, you need to store the cookie before reading each line so you can back up when you find it (sticking to walrus this time, since most people can probably use it by now):

```
with open('sampletext.txt', "r+") as f:
    cookie = 0  # Don't need tell to seek back to start of file if first line matches
    while line := f.readline():
        if 'string' in line:
            f.seek(cookie)  # Revert to position before we read in most recent line
            f.truncate()
            break
        cookie = f.tell()   # Save off position cookie prior to reading next line
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to apply changes to original file, it's possible to do using [`.truncate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate) method of file object:

```py
with open(r"sampletext.txt", "r+") as f:
    while line := f.readline():
        if line.rstrip() == "string":  # line.startswith("string")
            f.truncate(f.tell())  # removes all content after current position
            break
```

Here we iterating over file until reach this *specific* line and resize stream to size of bytes we've already read *(to get it we use [`.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.tell))*.

Comment: This violates the spec; `f.tell()` on text files is not numeric offset, it's a "cookie" (an opaque number) that can be used to return to the same position in the file when passed to `seek`, but has no other meaning. It may work for some encodings and not for others. The only documented solution that works with text files would be to perform `f.seek(0, io.SEEK_CUR)` (or `f.seek(0, 1)`, or `f.seek(f.tell())`) to force the underlying handle actual position to match the logical position, then `f.truncate()` (no argument needed; it truncates to the current position by default).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I've tested with ASCII, UTF-8 and UTF-16 and it worked properly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it won't work as an implementation detail with certain encodings. I'm saying [the docs themselves say it's unreliable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell): "Return the current stream position as an opaque number. The number does not usually represent a number of bytes in the underlying binary storage." That second line appears to be a lie on CPython (it usually *is* the number of bytes in the underlying binary storage), but [the code is crazy](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.0/Modules/_io/textio.c#L2647) and can do weird stuff.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I've tried 5 different encodings with various char sizes and it works every time the same. Sometimes python docs keep restrictions which doesn't actual anymore. I think, this have been already fixed as I can't reproduce it *(python 3.9)*.